# Extract specific part of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I was simply wondering what would be the simplest and most efficient way of extracting a certain part of a dynamic string in PHP?

Per example, in this string:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xclep1_school-gyrls-something-like-a-party_music#hp-v-v13

I'd only like to extract (and insert in a variable) the: " xclep1_school-gyrls-something-like-a-party_music ".

The main goal is to take this part, insert it to this URL: http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/160x120/video/xclep1_school-gyrls-something-like-a-party_music so I can capture the thumbnail externally.

Sorry if this is a "newbie" question and thank you very much for your time. Any hint/code/php reference is appreciated.

Comment: The default solution for this is a regular expression. You would  define a rule, something along the lines of "the part of the string starting from the last `/` until an occurrence of `#` or the end of the string", and put that into a regex. Maybe one of our regex gurus will give you an expression to start with.

Comment: @Pekka Regex over parse_url? You need more coffee :)

Comment: @Gordon D'oh! You're right of course. :) I am slightly hung over. Need more coffee.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) over regex:

```
$segments = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

$segments will be an array containing all segments of the path info, e.g.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => video
    [2] => xclep1_school-gyrls-something-like-a-party_music
)
```

So you can do

```
echo $segments[2];
```

and get

```
`xclep1_school-gyrls-something-like-a-party_music`
```

Comment: As expected, it works perfectly. Thank you very(!) much for your kind help.

Now if I could just figure out why my question got downvoted...

Answer (score 4):

One of the following:

```
preg_match('~/[^/]*$~', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Or:

```
$parts = explode('/', $str);
echo array_pop($parts);
```

Or:

```
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, '/'));
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I actually tried several times with a preg_match, but sadly I'm not a regex-guru. I will try each of those and see which works best. Thank you again.

Comment: Did you forget the end part of the string `#hp-v-v13`?

Answer (score 2):

The [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function and extract the path. Explode on '/' and get the last element

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$url_parts = explode('/',$parsed_url['path']);
print_r($url_parts);
```